# mod rewrite compare parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have to add a parameter to an URL, but only in case the parameter is not already attached.

url: sub.mydomain.com
final: sub.domain.com/sub simple pattern example -> (sub).mydomain.com/(sub)

How can I compare if $1 != $2, to apply the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

my try doesn't work

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+).*?(?:[^/]+)?/(.*)?/ [NC]
#RewriteCond %1<->%2 !^$1<->$2
```